# Why we call Signal Handler twice?

Tags: c, linux, signals, signal-processing

I am a novice  to  signal handling  using c language. I  am analyzing below signal handling code which extracted from specific resource.

Here is that code .

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <signal.h>

    void intproc();
    void quitproc();

    main()
    {
      int i;

      signal(SIGINT,intproc);
      signal(SIGQUIT,quitproc);

      printf("Ctrl+c is disabled. Use ctrl+\\ to quit\n");

      for (i=0;;i++) {
        printf("In an infinite loop...\n"); 
        sleep(200);
        }
    }


    void intproc()
    {
      signal(SIGINT,intproc);
      printf("You have pressed ctrl+c.\n");
    }

    void quitproc()
    { signal(SIGQUIT,intproc);
      printf("You have pressed ctrl+\\. Now the program quits.\n");
      exit(0);
    }
```

what I want to know is why we call again Signal handler "(SIGINT,intproc)" inside intproc() function ?

I tried to run this code without that signal handler within that function ,and its also working .

Comment: signal handling is not in the C standard but in the Posix one.

Answer (score 3):

This is very old code. In the old days (perhaps SunOS3, 1990-s) a signal handler was automatically uninstalled when executed. See [signal(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signal.2.html) (difference between SysV and BSD behavior) and avoid using `signal`.

Carefully read [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) then use [sigaction(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html). Don't use `signal(2)`. Care about *async signal safe functions* (the only ones you can call from a signal handler; you should not use `printf` inside a signal handler!). Consider simply setting some `volatile sig_atomic_t` global (or `static`) variable inside your signal handler (and test it outside).

Read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) which explains these things in detail.

Answer (score 1):

After the function `intproc` has completed, the program carries on, but the signal action is restored to the default. When it receives a second `SIGINT` signal, the program takes the default action, which is to terminate the program.

If you want to retain the signal handler, you would need to re-establish it by calling `signal` again.

This is the reason you should always prefer the more robust `sigaction` over the `signal` function.